# How does one change the angle of a gradient added by VLA-AddHatch in AutoCAD?

Tags: autocad, autolisp

I am creating a gradient inside of a LWPolyLine with the code

```
(progn
    (setq hatch (vla-addHatch mspace 
                              acPreDefinedGradient
                              "LINEAR"
                              :vlax-true
                              acGradientObject)
    )
    (vlax-put hatch 'PatternAngle (/ pi 2))
    (vlax-invoke hatch 'AppendOuterLoop (list pline))
    (vla-evaluate hatch)
)
```

The problem occurs when trying to set the `PatternAngle`. I get the error:

```
Error: AutoCAD.Application: Not applicable
```

Without that line, it works fine. The gradient is just rotated by 90 degrees.

What am I doing wrong? I have a feeling it has something to do with the `acPreDefinedGradient`. Like I shouldn't be using a predefined gradient. Possibly using `acUserDefinedGradient`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like I was supposed to use `GradientAngle`, not `PatternAngle`.

```
(progn
    (setq hatch (vla-addHatch mspace 
                              acPreDefinedGradient
                              "LINEAR"
                              :vlax-true
                              acGradientObject)
    )
    (vlax-put hatch 'GradientAngle (/ pi 2))
    (vlax-invoke hatch 'AppendOuterLoop (list pline))
    (vla-evaluate hatch)
)
```

Sheesh, I wish there was proper documentation on these things.